# I-series DSPPGMREF does not show external data structures

Tags: data-structures, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am amazed that I haven't been able to find this e-mail scouring all of the utilities on the AS400 and googling for hours.  Seems like this should be a thing.  But does anyone know of a utility similar to DSPPGMREF or an API that can be called to show me what versions of external data structures a program was compiled over on the i-series?  I have ran into an issue where a production program that appears to be the correct version receives an error when used, but when I re-compile from the supposed source the error no longer exists.  I suspect that the program in the change management library was compiled over a different version of data structure somewhere, but would like to be able to prove it.  Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the format level of the data structures used in a program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So when you use the `DSPPGMREF` command, does the external data structure show up in the listing of objects referenced?

Comment: No, they are not in there at all in any shape or form.

Comment: It's probably because the external definition is looked up at compile time and used in compilation, but then it is always the same, not referenced every time the program runs the way a file is.  If it is not being externally referenced at run-time, there is no reason to save where the definition came from. It is treated like an internally defined data structure.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. If there is, @Barbara Morris will know.

Comment: I'm sure there has to be some place where the program must know what the field structure is of the external data structure that is known to the program.  I'll bet it is in an IBM API somewhere, but got sidetracked on another prod problem so haven't had the chance yet to try to dig it up.  If I find anything, I'll post it back here.